Proving $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{x_0}{a} \cdot \frac{x_0+1}{a+1} \cdot \frac{x_0+2}{a+2} \cdots \frac{x_0+k-1}{a+k-1}=\left(\frac{x_0}{a}\right)^k$
I am trying to understand why for this sequence:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{x_0}{a} \cdot \frac{x_0+1}{a+1} \cdot \frac{x_0+2}{a+2} \cdots \frac{x_0+k-1}{a+k-1}=\left(\frac{x_0}{a}\right)^k$$
I started by taking the logarith of the original sequence:
$$\log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{x_0+i}{a+i}\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \log\left(\frac{x_0+i}{a+i}\right)$$
For large $k$, summations can be written as integrals:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \log\left(\frac{x_0+i}{a+i}\right) \approx \int_0^k \log\left(\frac{x_0+t}{a+t}\right) dt$$
I am not sure how to correctly proceed. Can someone please help?

This doesn't make sense. You can't have that $k\to\infty$ in the LHS but that $k$ is some fixed number in the RHS.

The OP may want to discuss asymptotic behavior, but here I am simply solving the left-hand-side limit.

Assume $x_0>a>0$, then
$$\begin{align*}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{x_0+i}{a+i}}=&\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left( 1+\frac{x_0-a}{a+i} \right)}\\>&1+\left( x_0-a \right) \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{1}{a+i}}\end{align*}$$
consider
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{1}{a+i}}\ge \sum_{i=\lceil a \rceil}^{k+\lfloor a \rfloor-1}{\frac{1}{i}}=&\int_{\lceil a \rceil}^{k+\lfloor a \rfloor}{\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}\mathrm{d}x}\\\ge& \int_{\lceil a \rceil}^k{\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x}=\ln \frac{k}{\lceil a \rceil}\end{align*}$$
We get
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{x_0+i}{a+i}}>\left( x_0-a \right) \ln k+\left( 1-\left( x_0-a \right) \ln \lceil a \rceil \right) $$
So when we set $k\to+\infty$, the limit is $+\infty$.
So, when $a>x_0>0$, the limit is $0$.

For the situation that one of $x_0,\ a$ is negative, we can split the product into two parts, the second of which, $\underset{i=\lceil \max \left\{ \left| x_0 \right|,\left| a \right| \right\} \rceil }{\overset{k-1}{\prod}}\frac{x_0+i}{a+i}$ ($k$ is so large that $k-1\ge i$) is always positive. This part still tends to $+\infty$ when $x_0>a$, so the positive or negative sign of the entire limit infinity depends on the sign of the first part.

Therefore, the limit is
$$\begin{cases}
 0&  \text{if }x_0<a,\\
 \mathrm{sgn}\left(\underset{i=0}{\overset{\lfloor \max \left\{ \left| x_0 \right|,\left| a \right| \right\}\rfloor}{\prod}}{\frac{x_0+i}{a+i}} \right) \infty&  \text{if }x_0>a\\
\end{cases}$$

@ Soriak: thank you so much for your answer! do you think your analysis can be applied to this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4973416/approximating-a-sequence-in-limits

@stats_noob, I am not familiar with statistics. But intuitively, I feel that this result (the limit tends to $0$) may be useful, and the calculation method should have nothing to do with your that question. Best wishes.
