Approximating a sequence in limits
Here are the moments for a beta distribution:
$$\text{For } X \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta), \text{ the k-th moment is given by:}$$
$$E[X^k] = \frac{B(\alpha+k, \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}$$
I expanded :
$$\frac{B(\alpha+k, \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+k)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}$$
$$= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+k)}$$
Using rising factorial notation:
$$(\alpha)_k = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$
$$E[X^k] = \frac{(\alpha)_k}{(\alpha+\beta)_k}$$

Now, suppose I have this sequence of moments (here, the $k$ terms on both sides are an exponent):
$$E[Y_{\infty}^k] = (\frac{x_0}{a})^k$$

For the above Beta Distribution, if we set $\alpha = x_0$ and $\beta = a - x_0$, we get (on the right hand side, the $k$ terms are rising factorials but on the left hand side the $k$ terms are exponents):
$$E[X^k] = \frac{(x_0)_k}{(a)_k}$$
Expand this:
$$\frac{(x_0)_k}{(a)_k} = \frac{x_0(x_0+1)(x_0+2)...(x_0+k-1)}{a(a+1)(a+2)...(a+k-1)}$$
$$= \frac{x_0}{a} \cdot \frac{x_0+1}{a+1} \cdot \frac{x_0+2}{a+2} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{x_0+k-1}{a+k-1}$$

I am trying to prove:
$$Y_{\infty} \sim Beta(x_0, a-x_0)$$
Can someone please help me do this? Can this be done using mathematical induction?

this seems related to your previous question

You write $E[Y_\infty^k] = (\frac{x_0}{a})^k$ and $E[Y_\infty^k] = \frac{(x_0)_k}{(a)_k}$. The two are contradictory. You need the second one to prove what you are looking for.

@Thomas: thank you... I will correct this ...

Now there is only one equality, but it’s the wrong one :)
If $Y_\infty$ and $X$ have the same distribution (Beta$(x_0, a-x_0)$) then they must have the same moments, but here even the second moment of $Y_\infty$ and $X$ are different.

:( i have been working on this problem for more than a week now ... my brain is "alphabet soup" at this point...

@ThomasLehéricy : Hi Thomas, can you please help me with this question? Thank you so much

Wei’s answer contains everything. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166637/do-moments-define-distributions

The MGF of the Beta distribution is finite for all $t>0$, so it is characterised by its moments - see here. Therefore if $Y_\infty$ has the same moments as a Beta distribution then you may conclude that $Y_\infty$ is distributed according to that same Beta distribution.

Assuming $x_0,a$ are constants and you really meant your equation be an exponent, writing:
$$
Y_\infty = \frac{x_0}aY
$$
you just reduce to the case:
$$
E(Y^k)=1
$$
for all $k\in\mathbb N$.
Assuming regularity, you only have the obvious constant solution $Y=1$. Beta distributions will not work, at best you can view the previous example as the limit $\alpha\to\infty$.
